# python index errors when indexing in if else statement directly

Tags: python, indexing

when i trying to solve ctf challange, i got indexing errors but i don't know what's a problem with my code

if i run this code

```
import string

arr1 = ['21', 'cf', '28', 'd6', '77', 'a3', '27', 'd2', '77', '2f', '85', '04', 'db', '35', '4d', '6f', 'a5', 'c3', 'd8', '64', '85', 'fe', '64', '6b', 'c0', '14', '5c', '13', '5f', '49', '0f', 'df', 'd8']
arr2 = ['73', '8a', '6c', '84', '32', 'e7', '75', '97', '33', '7d', 'c0', '40', '89', '70', '09', '3d', 'e0', '87', '8a', '21', 'c1', 'ac', '21', '2f', '92', '51', '18', '41', '1a', '0d', '5d', '9a', '9c']

txt = ''
i = 0
while (i < 33):
    for a in string.printable:
        if ord(a) ^ int(arr1[i], 16) ^ int(arr2[i], 16) == 0:
            txt += a
            i += 1
print(txt)
```

i got this errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 9, in <module>
    if ord(a) ^ int(arr1[i], 16) ^ int(arr2[i], 16) == 0:
                    ~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but if i store arr1[i] or arr2[i] to another variable like this

```
import string

arr1 = ['21', 'cf', '28', 'd6', '77', 'a3', '27', 'd2', '77', '2f', '85', '04', 'db', '35', '4d', '6f', 'a5', 'c3', 'd8', '64', '85', 'fe', '64', '6b', 'c0', '14', '5c', '13', '5f', '49', '0f', 'df', 'd8']
arr2 = ['73', '8a', '6c', '84', '32', 'e7', '75', '97', '33', '7d', 'c0', '40', '89', '70', '09', '3d', 'e0', '87', '8a', '21', 'c1', 'ac', '21', '2f', '92', '51', '18', '41', '1a', '0d', '5d', '9a', '9c']

txt = ''
i = 0
while (i < 33):
    x = arr1[i]
    y = arr2[i]
    for a in string.printable:
        if ord(a) ^ int(x, 16) ^ int(y, 16) == 0:
            txt += a
            i += 1
print(txt)
```

i got no errors. how that possible?

Comment: in your first example you are reevaluating `arr[i]` as i changes in the for loop. In the second, you are evaluating `arr[i]` once per loop in the while loop, so the changes in `i` do not affect it as it changes in the for loop.

Comment: Get rid of `i` altogether and use the more pythonic `for x, y in zip(arr1, arr2):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example:

```
for a in string.printable:
    if ord(a) ^ int(arr1[i], 16) ^ int(arr2[i], 16) == 0:
        txt += a
        i += 1
```

When `i` is incremented inside the for loop, its new value will be used in the next loop iteration.

But in the second example:

```
x = arr1[i]
y = arr2[i]
for a in string.printable:
    if ord(a) ^ int(x, 16) ^ int(y, 16) == 0:
        txt += a
        i += 1
```

`x = arr1[i]` is assigned *only once*, and any further increments to `i` do not affect `x`.

It seems like you expected `x = arr1[i]` to be some kind of ongoing permanent formula, so that changing i *would* affect x.  But that is not so.

Comment: you're right, i forgot if its not break